# Google App Engine module and custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

I'm trying to assign custom domain to App Engine module. At the moment I have staging.example.com pointed to app-id.appspot.com and that works correctly but I also want to assign api.staging.example.com to api.app-id.appspot.com. I've created CNAME record from api.staging.example.com to ghs.googlehosted.com, added api.staging.domain.com in developers console/appengine/settings/custom domains and here is my dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "staging.example.com/*"
    module: default
  - url: "api.staging.example.com/*"
    module: api
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Every request to endpoints on api.staging.example.com shows only 404 error and I can't see this in the logs, it looks like api.staging.example.com is pointed to somewhere else, all request to api-app-id.appspot.com works correctly.

Comment: Have you added and mapped the **http://api.staging.example.com** to **https://api-dot-app-id.appspot.com** in the Google App Admin Console ?

Comment: No, where can I do that? I don't see option for mapping domains in Google App Admin Console (https://admin.google.com?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know where is my problem - Google Cloud Endpoints.

> Google Cloud Endpoints does not support custom domains.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384

Answer (score 0):

Are you making HTTPS requests? The [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url) note that double-wildcard domains are not supported for SSL certificates.

> Google recommends using the HTTPS protocol to send requests to your app. Google does not issue SSL certificates for double-wildcard domains hosted at appspot.com. Therefore with HTTPS you must use the string "-dot-" instead of "." to separate subdomains

So you'll need to replace the first `.` with `-dot-` to follow this pattern:
`https://module-dot-app-id.appspot.com`. In your case `api-dot-app-id.appspot.com`.

Comment: `https://api-dot-app-id.appspot.com` works correctly but I want to assign own subdomain (`http://api.staging.example.com`) to this module, maybe the problem is that I don't have SSL on api.staging.example.com?